# Delete git merge commit from local history

Tags: git, git-merge

My commit history looks like this:

[image: commit history]

Yellow is the master branch, blue and purple are feature branches. Commits 0-5 have been pushed, commits 6-10 are only local.

I want to undo the effect of merge commit 6, I mean delete it entirely, and reroute C7 to be the merge of C1 and C2.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be very easy, and since you will need some trial and error, better take a (local) copy of you git repo before doing this. Then try something like this:

```
git branch temp <sha-2>
git merge <sha-1>
git merge <sha-5>
git checkout master
git rebase temp
git branch -d temp
```

Comment: Creating the temp branch worked perfectly. I did not need the merge with C5 for what I intended, and instead of `git checkout master` I had to checkout C10, but the main strategy worked like a charm.